# VB.NET WMI OR WQL? Help

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that when it first starts i need it to run a database query.

I have all the database queries however forms are all loaded by this method.

dim myfrm as new Form2 
myfrm.show.

The thing is if this app has crashed etc i need to make sure its the first initial start of this program

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a App table with a version column, maybe step if you want more granularity.  If table doesn't exist, your are at your first version and than go on...  After all your query, put a version in the table.  That way, you will be able to check if those query have been run.